# How to spilt logs based on the specified size for daily basis?

Tags: logging, mule, log4j2

I want spilt logs based on the specified size for Daily basis using Log4j properties. Could you please suggest me how to use?

For example:

- If log exceeds to 1GB I need to stop log to be append and has to be create new log.
- Previous log should be available as well on daily basis.

Comment: You can use configure [`RollingFileAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.html) and set the `maximumFileSize` option.

Comment: In RollingFileAppendar, can we use daily basis ? how logs will create. MaxBackupIndex means no.of logs we can mention . if no of logs got created how the process will happend?

Comment: Is this log4net or log4j?

Comment: I linked you a doc ... like first line ... `RollingFileAppender can roll log files based on size or date or both depending on the setting of the RollingStyle property.`. Just rtm.